# How to search for overloaded methods in a class

Tags: java, eclipse, search, ide, signature

Is there an easy way to search in a java project, which methods in a Class have the same "name" ?

So for example for :

```
public class Banana{

void findBananas(Ananas ananas) { --- }

void findBananas(Bananas banana) { --- }

void findCiao(Ciao ciao) { --- }

void findCiao2(Ciao ciao) { --- }

}
```

The search have to specify that in Banana class there is a repetition of the method name "findBananas".

Any tools / ide appreciated.

Comment: *How to search methods with the same name in the same class*. These methods are known as overloaded methods. What you are looking for is a way to find `overloaded` methods. The way you explain it is an overkill.. That being said, do you want to do a text search or do you want to find them at runtime through reflection?

Comment: *I want to list the "duplicate" methods in all the classes in the Java project*. This is deviating from your initial requirement. Do you want to find duplicates across all the classes or duplicates within each class across all classes. Also, did you attempt anything at all? If no, this question could be a candidate for a coding request and may be closed.

Comment: Ok i deleted my answer, but you definitely can do all this with reflection. find every class in your program, loop for duplicate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated post. Old version removed**

You can use Reflection. I don't know your exact needs but this one works fine for my projects here is [git test project](https://github.com/varren/Java-Reflection/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/varren/RScanner.java)  :

You will need to use 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10' lib for this. Can download from here https://code.google.com/p/reflections/

```
public static class MethodInfo {
    Class fromClass;
    ArrayList<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();

    public MethodInfo(Class fromClass) {
        this.fromClass = fromClass;
    }
}

public static HashMap<String, MethodInfo>
        findOverloadedMethods(String packageToScan, boolean declaredInClass){

    Set<Class<?>> allClasses = findAllClassesInPackage(packageToScan);
    System.out.println("Number of Classes in "+ packageToScan 
                       +" = " + allClasses.size());

    HashMap<String, MethodInfo> map = new HashMap<String, MethodInfo>();

    for (Class c : allClasses) {
        try {
            findAllMethodsForClass(c, declaredInClass, map);
        }catch (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError e){
            //have no idea why some classes throw this NoClassDefFoundError
            System.err.println(c.getName() + ": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError");
        }
    }

    return map;
}
public static void findAllMethodsForClass(Class c, boolean declaredInClass, 
                                          HashMap<String, MethodInfo> map)
        throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError{
    //Set<Method> methods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(c);
    Method[] methods = declaredInClass ? c.getDeclaredMethods(): c.getMethods();

    for (Method method : methods) {
        String key = c.getName() + "." + method.getName();

        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, new MethodInfo(c));
        }

        MethodInfo methodInfo = map.get(key);
        methodInfo.methods.add(method);
    }
}
public static Set<Class<?>> findAllClassesInPackage(String packageToScan){
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner(),
            new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(packageToScan)));

    return reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
}

public static void print(HashMap<String, RScanner.MethodInfo> map){
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        RScanner.MethodInfo info = map.get(key);
        if (info.methods.size() > 1) {
            // wait method has 3 overloads in Object class
            if (!info.methods.get(0).getName().equals("wait"))
                System.out.println(key + " : " + info.methods.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this program just prints the method names and does not find overloaded methods. If you wish to have your program do all the talking, the least you can do is make it do what the OP wants :)

Comment: yep,but you can build up a logic on it

Comment: Yes. But it does not answer the question. It's more of a hint.

Comment: In addiction, I want to list the "duplicate" methods in all the classes in the Java project (that are hundreds, so I cannot list them as you do=

Comment: @Gaetano If you are still looking for some kind of solution, take a look at updated post.

Comment: it seems that this jar is not sufficient: 
org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10

at runtime it misses some classes,

Comment: @Gaetano Yep, you can add something like this if you want:  `compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:2.0'
    compile 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` but i think it works fine without them, if you don't use features related to this libs